# SQL Server 2012 join query

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables: `Fields{id, testid, labid, upperlimit, lowerlimit)` and `LabTest{id, testid, labid, upperlimit, lowerlimit)`

```
Sample data: Fields: 0, testid1, 1, 10, 20
                     1, testid2, 2, 10, 20

             LabTest: 0, testid1, 1, 40, 50
                      1, testid1, null, 50, 60
                      2, testid2, null, 55, 67
                      3, testid2, null, 67, 78
                      4, testid2, null, 78, 89
```

> join on testid1 should return 1 line
>
> join on testid2 should return 3 lines

If `labid` in Fields table is not null and `testid` is not null then I need to use the `upperlimit` and `lowerlimit` of the `LabTest` table where `Fields.testid=LabTest.testid` and `Fields.labid=LabTest.labid`

If I use a left join (because I need to take the Fields without testid also):

```
select * from Fields left join LabTest on Fields.testid=LabTest.testid
```

I will get back all the fields no matter if their `labid` is null or not (5 lines using the above sample data), but

> what I want to get is only one line the one with LabTest.labid not
>   null and if this doesnt exist then and only then I want to get the
>   line(s) with LabTest.labid = null

Comment: Please tag the correct RDBMS, and only the correct RDBMS. MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products.

Comment: use an `inner join` and put both conditions there: `Fields.testid=LabTest.testid and Fields.labid=LabTest.labid`

Comment: @Lamak I just edited my question why I use `left join`

Answer (score 1):

Use Inner Join or If filter the Left join with a Where Clause

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    select 
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Fields.Id ORDER BY labid),
      Fields_Id = Fields.id,
      Fields_testid = Fields.testid,
      Fields_labid = Fields.labid,
      Fields_upperlimit = Fields.upperlimit,
      Fields_lowerlimit = Fields.lowerlimit,

      LabTest_Id = LabTest.id, 
      LabTest_testid = LabTest.testid, 
      LabTest_labid = LabTest.labid,
      LabTest_upperlimit = LabTest.upperlimit, 
      LabTest_lowerlimit = LabTest.lowerlimit
      from Fields 
          left join LabTest 
        on Fields.testid=LabTest.testid

)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: User specified one row.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Please see the updated answer. You can't choose top 1 because there can be multiple ID's

Comment: It is not working, I have to change RN = x to find the row with the correct values

Comment: Try with ORDER BY labid DESC

Comment: It looks that is working, but when a Field has multiple LabTests with labid = null and none with labid not null I get only one line, but I need to get all of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select top 1   *
 from Fields left join LabTest
 on Fields.testid=LabTest.testid
where LabTest.labid is not null
```